# How to export html report from newman

Tags: postman, newman

I am using newman via node. Here is the code I'm running:

```
//File is named newmanRunner.js
const fs = require('fs'),
newman = require('newman');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('collections/optionsFile.json');
let optionsJson = JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(optionsJson);

newman.run(optionsJson, function(err){
    if(err){console.log("Error in collection run: " , err)};
    console.log('Collection run complete');
});
```

Here is the json file with the runtime options:

```
{
    "collection": "collections/my_collection.json",
    "data": "data/datafiles/someData.json",
    "environment": "data/environments/testEnvironment.json",
    "globals": "data/global/globalVars.json",
    "iterationCount": 1,
    "reporters": "html",
    "reporter-html-export": "reports/report.html"
}
```

I run the collection by the following command:

```
node newmanRunner.js
```

The problem I run into is that the html report is generated in a directory titled 'newman' which is in the same directory from which I'm running. I'd like the file to saved to the 'reports' directory. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on how to include the runtime options in a json file that can be loaded at runtime.

```
node: 6.11.2
newman: 3.8.3
os: macOS 10.13.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is usual I found the needed documentation shortly after posting the question. Anyway, posting here to hopefully help someone in the future.

[Newman Run Events](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#newmanrunevents)

Look at the options.reporters and options.reporter sections. They aren't super intuitive so here is my json file working as expected:

```
{
    "collection": "collections/my_collection.json",
    "data": "data/datafiles/someData.json",
    "environment": "data/environments/testEnvironment.json",
    "globals": "data/global/globalVars.json",
    "iterationCount": 1,
    "reporters": "html",
    "reporter": { "html": {"export": "reports/report.html"} }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to accept your own answer to close out this question. :)